# Variance Matrix Estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

We are given data $x_i=(x_{i1},x_{i2},...,x_{iq})^T$, $i=1,...,n$ with mean $$m_x:=m=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\begin{array}{c} x_{i,1} \\\vdots \\ x_{i,q} \end{array}\right)= \left(\begin{array}{c}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i,1} \\\vdots \\ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i,q} \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} m_{1} \\\vdots \\ m_{q} \end{array}\right)\in R^q$$ and a constant vector $a\in R^q$.

I need to show that:

i)$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-m)(x_i-m)^T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T-mm^T$$

ii)$$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n(x_i-a)(x_j-a)^T=(m-a)(m-a)^T$$

I might use the fact that for vectors $a,b,c,d$ with appropriate dimension it holds that $$(a+b)(c+d)^T=ac^T+ad^T+bc^T+bd^T$$

I tried i) for a long long time now but I always get a $1/n^2$ in the $mm^T$ part of the expression which destroys the whole thing... just to let you know if this notation confused as much as it did confuse me: $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T-mm^T$ is a $qxq$-Matrix.

//Edit: Solution for i
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-m)(x_i-m)^T \\ 
=& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_ix_i^T -x_im^T-mx_i^T+mm^T) \\
=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_im^T- \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n mx_i^T+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n mm^T \\
=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_im^T- m \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^T+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n mm^T \\
=& \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T - mm^T- m m^T+\frac{1}{n}n mm^T \\
=&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_ix_i^T-mm^T
\end{align*}
ii) similar to i)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery you are absolutely right, yes.

Comment: Maybe you could update the question to include your work? I haven't sat down to work out the details, but my instinct is that the matrix algebra fact you cited should do the trick (at least for the first one). The proof feels like it should be similar in principle to the proof that $\mathbb E[(X - \mu)^2] = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mu^2$ -- the middle terms in the quadratic expansion should presumably cancel out the back term and leave a net negative $1$ copy of $m m^T$. (Again, I haven't worked out the details, so I could be wrong.)

Comment: I edited the solution, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I'm a bit confused now -- didn't you arrive at the right solution for (i), apparently? I don't see the extra $1/n^2$ terms you claimed.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did find the solution in the end. There are no problems regaring thr $1/n^2$. As you said the middle terms cancel out the back term.